# Pokerstars Download Using Wine

Tags: wine

I have downloaded wine 1.6 from here: https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu I then downloaded the pokerstars from here: http://www.pokerstars.net/poker/download/

Both downloads went fine (I think) but when I try to open the pokerstars client it connects and then just opens a small black box at the top left of my screen and that is it.

Does anybody have any ideas about what might be going wrong?

Thanks for any help

Comment: First off, is there any reason why you downloaded Wine manually instead of using the version in the official repos? `sudo apt-get install wine` should get you a Wine version that's been tested with Ubuntu, and you'll get updates and fixes automatically. Second, how exactly did you "Open the PokerStars client"? The first step is to run `wine PokerStarsInstall.exe`; then only once installation was successful, you can actually run the client with Wine. I can at least tell you that in principle PokerStars is running great with Wine :)

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa Hey, no there was no reason, I just couldn't find it in the software center and I'm not great with the old terminal yet. Do you know how I can un-install these things so as to re-install them?

Comment: I've just had a look at those instructions you linked to. Those are instructions to install Wine from PPA. You can remove it again by running `sudo apt-get remove wine1.6` (or `wine1.7`, depending on which one you installed), then `sudo apt-get autoremove`, then `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`, then `sudo apt-get update`. Not sure why you couldn't fine Wine in the Software Center, [it's in the universe repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/wine). Maybe you don't have universe enabled?

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa Cool thanks, will I now need to re-install pokerstars? If so do you happen to know how to remove that as well? Thanks for all the help

Comment: So you *did* install the PokerStars client successfully? You went through that "InstallShield"-whatever-thingy (which I think is Windows' equivalent of good old `apt-get`), and got a message that PokerStars was successfully installed? In that case, it should be in your Wine fake-C partition (or wherever you installed it). So then you would execute the client as `wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/PokerStars/pokerstars.exe` or similar (and there are probably all kinds of fancy GUIs that will do this for you, but there I'm not an expert). Or how do you launch the client, exactly?

Answer (score 4):

You need to update Wine to 1.7.

Run this 3 commands to do so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

You **don't** need to reinstall PokerStars, just install wine 1.7 and run PokerStars again.

Good Luck!

Comment: I was having the same issue and this fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Wine(Wiki)](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), do the following on your terminal command line:

```
 wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
 sudo apt-key add Release.key
 sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu
```

and then (for the Stable branch),

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

you're done!

- You can also install from Devel, via:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
  ```

  or from Staging branch:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
  ```