# I'm having difficulties opening Poker Stars

Tags: 12.04

I have a problem running an updated version of Poker Stars using Wine. It run, but all I get is a grey window.

Comment: This issue is solved updating wine to 1.7.

Look [this answer.][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/524685/pokerstars-download-using-wine/568378#568378

Answer (score 0):

Today I've SOLVED this problem. 
Just install your PokerStars in Windows OS (I have Virtual Box running with Windows XP), make sure you can run in Windows, compress your installed PokerStars directory (it will be in C:/Program files/PokerStars.eu  and copy to Ubuntu your /home directory doesn't mater where. Unzip. Than install Wine if you don't have. If you have installed your previous PokerStars in Wine just remove everything from Wine. 
Than go to your unzipped directory, press right mouse button on PokerStars.exe and enjoy playing again!

For me it works! Is still using the Wine, but you're opening from your copied software from Windows OS.

If you have questions please ask,

Cheers!